# Launching browser windows from Ruby command prompt

Tags: ruby, search, browser

I've got this code below.  What I'd like it to do is launch each of the search queries I've specified into browser windows, instead of listing the search results as it's currently written to do.  But I'm a beginner and having a difficult time finding documentation on this.  Is it possible?

The issue is the actual list of search_criteria I will be using is actually 40 terms long and I need to do it for dozens and dozens of cities - which is why I was looking to automate the search process.

If it's not possible to launch each query as a browser window (or better tabs in a browser window) is there a way to specify each URL that results in some systematic way so as to be called by Ruby from command prompt to launch as a browser window?

```
require "google-search"

search_criteria = ["makers", "makerspaces", "fablabs", "smartlabs"]

#City name
search_1 = search_criteria.map do |noun|
    "#{noun} new york city"
end

#City acronym 1
search_2 = search_criteria.map do |noun|
    "#{noun} new york"
end

#City acronym 2
search_3 = search_criteria.map do |noun|
    "#{noun} nyc"
end


#Replace "search_1" for other acronyms
search_1.each do |query|
    puts "Just one moment please! I am searching for #{query}"
    Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
        search.query = query
        search.size = :large
    end.each { |item| puts item.title }
end
```

Comment: Use selenium-webdriver, create a driver and customize it as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search_criteria = ["makers", "makerspaces", "fablabs", "smartlabs"]
names = ["new+york+city", "new+york", "nyc"]

query_strings = names.map do |name|
  "#{name}+#{search_criteria.join('+')}" 
end

urls = query_strings.map do |q|
  "google.com/search?q=" + q
end

cmd_line = urls.join(' ')
```

Then you pass `cmd_line` to the Google Chrom executable via the `system()` call. On Mac OS X it would be like this:

```
system("/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --url #{cmd_line}")
```

Chrome will then open each url in the string passed to it in it's own tab in a new window. 
If you are using Windows you will have to find where the chrome.exe executable is buried, and in Linux you would just find the chrome binary to call it. Everything before the last part of ...`Chrome --url #{cmd_line}")` is just the path to the executable, which is buried inside the "Google Chrome.app" container on OS X.